# lua : storing values in string array and printing a value by calling a random index

Tags: arrays, string, random, lua, lua-table

i have a table named `t`

```
t = {"hi","hello","hola","whats up"}
```

and i want to be able to index the elements so that

```
hi = 1
hello = 2
hola = 3
whats up = 4
```

so that this random number generator

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
ranNumber = math.random(4)
```

can call on the tables elements and have a 25% probability of printing one element

if you dont understand, the java equivalent of this program would work like this

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;

public class PrintRandom{

 public static void main(String []args){

    String[] names={"hi", "hello", "hola", "whats up"};
    Random r=new Random();
    int RandomNumber=r.nextInt(4);

    System.out.println(names[RandomNumber]);
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not see your question. is it how to index your array? `t[ranNumber]`?

Comment: yes thats what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

To index the elements in the way you have described you should be able to do it like this:

```
t = {}
t["hi"] = 1
t["hello"] = 2
```

and so on.

For example:

```
print(t["hi"])
```

would then print 1.

Alternatively:

```
t[1] = {"hi", 1}
t[2] = {"hello", 2}
```

and access using:

```
print(t[1][1]) or print(t[1][2])
```

Hope that helps!